# Is there a way to configure 2 property system in same @Value ins spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, system-properties

I trying to use 2 different property files with the same parameters which every parameter is describing the same property for example: 
NewsPaperConsumer.properties, MarketConsumer.properties when every file have the same parameters. 
My aim is to use the separated way to make the configuration files more readable but at the progromatic side union them to one hash map for example:
`NewPaperConsumer` and `MarketConsumer` have the parameter **serverAddress**  so I'll get it by:

```
@Value("${serverAddress}")
private HashMap<String,String> serverAdresses;
```

how I change the way the system property save the parameter (instead of assign the value to string that It will assign it to hash map - {"key" : "value }